# Search several pdf file content in a folder for a string from text, if found copy to different folder

Tags: powershell, vbscript

My vbs and powershell skills are very limited but i've been tasked with something i need some help on.  The as is following. 
  I have folder called C:\temp\pdf, this folder contains approx 20,000 pdf files.  In the same folder i have a text file (.txt) with 3000 lines.  Each line has just an ID number like 12345, next line 45678, next line 59385 etc... I need a way to scan the content of all 20,000 files and when the ID matches copy the file into another folder.  At the end i'll have a new folder with 3000 files. Unfortunately i can't install any .dll files and have to use vbs, powershell or cmd to do this task.
 Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Windows doesn't have any built-in PDF-scanning/searching functionality, so you really won't get anywhere with your current constraints :) are you allowed to upload your pdf files to some service on the internet to scan them for you?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217557/find-specific-sentence-in-a-web-page-using-powershell You could try invoking the PDF as a Web Page (`file:///C:/temp/pdf/file1.pdf`) in a Browser and see if you can search it that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search in PDF files and move them using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925530/how-to-search-in-pdf-files-and-move-them-using-powershell)

Answer (score -1):

If you have MS Word, you can open/convert the PDF files in MS Word then do the reading of each line in MS Word while traversing each row of your txt file and comparing it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).